# marquee not showing all text

Tags: html, css, blogger, marquee

This snippet doesnt show all the text (around 700 words spread over 100 lines/paragraphs).
Just shows around 10 lines/paragraphs and then repeat these contente.

```css
.marquee {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 410px;
overflow: hidden;
animation: marquee 8s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes marquee {
0% {top: 10em}
100% {top: -2em}
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">text</p>
```

What is missing and/or what is wrong that cause this situation?

Some help please to enable this marquee of showing all texto.

Best regards,

Rubasi

Comment: can you attach a screenshot in that case? there is a limit of 30000 characters allowed in snippets

Comment: 719 words | 4794 characters including spaces | 128 paragraphs | 199 lines Thus the problem isnt the text. Some more help? Please!

Comment: my bad there is nothing to do with the limitation in the snippet. Its a css property issue. try the answer i just uploaded,

Comment: hey Lakindu! Thx for helping me. css added = marquee scrolling all text :) now its time to insert <p class="marquee"> on every single paragraph :0 Its really importante to put on every single one? or could be just <p class="marquee"> on top and </p> on bottom?

Comment: that actually depends on how you want to show the text. If you add one <p></p> tag, there will be no line breaks. But if you add more tags, you can break lines by default without any other css alternations. Please put a tick if this solves the issue :)

Comment: Seems its not need to insert <p class="marquee"> on every paragraph because the text keeps the line break/space between them just with <p class="marquee" on top and </p> on the bottom of the text. ;)

Comment: great now its solved right? please do put a tick :) as an appreciation

Comment: but overlay: hidden is not working and height is not working too.:(( The text must keep scrolling 'behind' the image and the the tex must start scroll 'respecting' the height (410px). Follows the url  wheres the marquee is placed http://www.festasparapalmoemeio.pt/ to better understand the issues and be able to helping me to solve them. THX

Comment: I was hoping/wishing that you could help me to fix/solve the 3 issues (shows all text + overlat: hidden + height). Im not intent to play with users here. Sorry If youre feeling/thinking that. Seems that Ive to make another more question/s to solve the two issues mentioned above. I will do it right now. Thx again for your partial help. ;/

Comment: now Ive to wait 90m to can make another question to get some help about the 2 other issues. Gr 8(

Comment: I have edited the answer, i think its working now. check the snippet

Comment: I knew this snippet and I had tried before. Doesnt work for me. :( Looking forward for some adjustments on the snippet placed on my blogger page to solve the 2 issues.

Comment: maybe some other class names overriding this. are you using any pre defined templates or libraries in your website? If you run the below snippet independently it works.

Comment: Its a native (mínima lefty) blogger template costumize (website masked). Meanwhile I found.the follow snippet thats works as I want... but I cant make it with color #0093dd which is the color I set it up as post-body text color. :( Maybe you could help me to solve this color issue. Please!

Comment: I will put the snippet in my blog and here in other question soon as I could make a new question. Few minutes left. Stay tuned pls.

Comment: I added the mentioned color in the font color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following css propertyin order to show the content.

```
.marquee p
{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Try the snippet

```css
.areas {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marquee {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
  color: #0093dd;
}


/* Make it move! */

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    top: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}


/* Make it look pretty */

.microsoft .marquee {
  font: 1em 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

.microsoft:before,
.microsoft::before,
.microsoft:after,
.microsoft::after {
  z-index: 1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFF, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

.microsoft:after,
.microsoft::after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.microsoft:before,
.microsoft::before {}
```

```html
<div class="microsoft areas">
  <p class="marquee">
    Paragraphs are the building blocks of papers. Many students define paragraphs in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the unity and coherence of ideas among sentences
    is what constitutes a paragraph. A paragraph is defined as “a group of sentences or a single sentence that forms a unit” (Lunsford and Connors 116). Length and appearance do not determine whether a section in a paper is a paragraph. For instance,
    in some styles of writing, particularly journalistic styles, a paragraph can be just one sentence long. Ultimately, a paragraph is a sentence or group of sentences that support one main idea. In this handout, we will refer to this as the “controlling
    idea,” because it controls what happens in the rest of the paragraph.
    <br><br> Before you can begin to determine what the composition of a particular paragraph will be, you must first decide on an argument and a working thesis statement for your paper. What is the most important idea that you are trying to convey to
    your reader? The information in each paragraph must be related to that idea. In other words, your paragraphs should remind your reader that there is a recurrent relationship between your thesis and the information in each paragraph. A working thesis
    functions like a seed from which your paper, and your ideas, will grow. The whole process is an organic one—a natural progression from a seed to a full-blown paper where there are direct, familial relationships between all of the ideas in the paper.
    <br><br> The decision about what to put into your paragraphs begins with the germination of a seed of ideas; this “germination process” is better known as brainstorming. There are many techniques for brainstorming; whichever one you choose, this stage
    of paragraph development cannot be skipped. Building paragraphs can be like building a skyscraper: there must be a well-planned foundation that supports what you are building. Any cracks, inconsistencies, or other corruptions of the foundation can
    cause your whole paper to crumble.
    <br><br> So, let’s suppose that you have done some brainstorming to develop your thesis. What else should you keep in mind as you begin to create paragraphs? Every paragraph in a paper should be:
    <br><br>

    <b>Unified:</b> All of the sentences in a single paragraph should be related to a single controlling idea (often expressed in the topic sentence of the paragraph). Clearly related to the thesis: The sentences should all refer to the central idea,
    or thesis, of the paper (Rosen and Behrens 119).

    <br><br>
    <b>Coherent:</b> The sentences should be arranged in a logical manner and should follow a definite plan for development (Rosen and Behrens 119).
  </p>
</div>
```